# Force Customer to Check Box Acknowledging they Have Read a Document

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, product

I have a WooCommerce site that has a couple of products that have been getting a lot of returns due to them ordering the wrong thing. I have added a "Cheat Sheet" that the customer can reference via Advanced Custom Fields. I have written the below code to force them to check the box to acknowledge that they have read it before they can add the product to the cart.

The problem is that no matter if they check the box or not, I get the custom error message displayed. So obviously I have a flaw in my logic, but I can't pinpoint it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php
// Add Confirmation Checkbox on Product Single  
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_cheat_sheet_confirm', 29 );  
    function woocommerce_cheat_sheet_confirm() {
        global $post;
        $cheat_sheet = get_field('cheat_sheet'); // Get Advanced Custom Field
        if ( ! empty( $cheat_sheet ) ) { // If it exists, add the confirmation box ?>                   
            <div id="cheat-sheet-confirmation" class="checkbox">
                <form>  
                    <label>
                        <input id="cheatsheetconfirm" name="cheatsheetconfirm" type="checkbox" value="isconfirmed"> I confirm that I have read the <a href="<?php echo $cheat_sheet['url']; ?>" />cheat sheet</a>.
                    </label>
                </form>
            </div>
        <?php } 
    }

    function cheatsheetConfirmation() { 
    if(isset($_REQUEST['cheatsheetconfirm']) && $_REQUEST['cheatsheetconfirm'] == 'on'){
        $is_checked = true;   
    }
    else {
        $is_checked = false;
    }

    if ($is_checked == false) {
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Please acknowledge that you have read the cheat sheet.', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'cheatsheetConfirmation', 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score 5):

The error is here.

```
<input id="cheatsheetconfirm" name="cheatsheetconfirm" type="checkbox" value="isconfirmed"> I confirm that I have read the <a href="<?php echo $cheat_sheet['url']; ?>">cheat sheet</a>
```

Change it to this

```
<input id="cheatsheetconfirm" name="cheatsheetconfirm" type="checkbox" value="on"> I confirm that I have read the <a href="<?php echo $cheat_sheet['url']; ?>">cheat sheet</a>
```

#### Explanation

I changed the `value` of the `<input>` tag.

You were correct that the logic was wrong. You were checking the value of `$_REQUEST['cheatsheetconfirm']` which is set to post "isconfirmed". This means that your if statement returns false since you want `$_REQUEST['cheatsheetconfirm']` to equal "isconfirmed" and not "on".

If you change the value that is submitted via the form then your if statement will return true.

Comment: This is the correct answer. You may also want to do a boolean check along with `if ( ! empty( $cheat_sheet ) )` as ACF will return false if the field was not submitted with the post. Probably not a big deal since you created it, but just for good measure. It would turn into: `if ( $cheat_sheet && ! empty( $cheat_sheet ) ) { // true }`

Comment: Thank you for this, however it still keeps giving me the validation error with the box checked & unchecked. So I'm pretty sure I still have some logic issues to work through. Thank you for your time though

Comment: Can you show me the error? I'll have a look if we can fix it.